# Call to a member function toArray() on integer

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

***User.php***

```
public function role()
{

    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Role','user_role','user_id','role_id');

}

//проверка принадлежит ли пользователь к какой либо роли
public function  isEmloyee(){
    $role=$this->role->toArray();
    return !empty($role);
}
//проверка имеетли пользователь определению роли
public function hasRole($check){

    return in_array($check,array_pluck($this->role->toArray(),'name'));
}
//получение идентификатора роли
private function getIdinArray($array,$term){
    foreach ($array as $key => $value){
        if ($value == $term){
            return $key +1;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
//добавление роли пользователя
public function makeEmployee($title){
    $assiqned_role = array();
    $role = array_pluck(Role::all()->toArray(),'name');
    switch ($title){
        case 'admin':
            $assiqned_role[] = $this->getIdinArray($role,'admin');
        case 'client':
            $assiqned_role[] = $this->getIdinArray($role,'client');
            break;
        default:
            $assiqned_roles[] = false;
    }
    $this->role()->attach($assiqned_role);
}
```

***Role.php***

```
class Role extends Model
{

   public function users()
   {

       return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\User','user_role','role_id');
   }

}
```

***OwnerMiddleware.php***

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;


class OwnerMiddleware
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next,$role)
    {

        if(!$request->user()->hasRole($role)) {
            return redirect('/');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Comment: The error seems to indicate the issue. So find out why it’s an integer at the call-site and work backwards from there

Comment: You have a number of instances of `->toArray()` in your code. Which one is throwing the error? At a glance, I don't think any of them would (they should all be instances of a `Collection`, which has `->toArray()` function). Also, note on naming; `public function role()` suggests it returns **a single** `Role` instance, but it's a `belongsToMany()`, which returns **multiple** `Role` instances, so it should be the plural `public function roles()`.

Comment: he gives an error  public function hasRole($check)

Comment: @QIPS, `$this->role` always must be a collection (not integer), except if you have `role` column in `users` table or `role` attribute in `User` model.

Comment: how can I write it all, write the code if not difficult

Comment: @QIPS, Please, attach all User.php code and Users table columns.

Comment: protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password', 'surname', 'patronymic', 'iin', 'number', 'groupinvalid'
    ];

Comment: fails to attach gives an error the only way through the comment

Comment: @QIPS, And users table columns?

Comment: from the database?

Comment: @QIPS yes from database

Comment: it is scrrin https://prnt.sc/pzrqhc

Answer (score 0):

You have `role` column in database. It preserves access to your `role` relation collection. You should delete it or rename `role()` relation for example to `roles()`. Moreover, `belongsToMany` implies that user can have many roles.

In addition, I want to note that the collection has its own methods `in_array` => `contains`, `array_pluck => pluck`. You could optimize your code like that:

```
public function roles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class, 'user_role');
}

public function isEmloyee(){
    return $this->roles->isNotEmpty();
}

public function hasRole($name){
    return $this->roles->pluck('name')->contains($name);
}

public function makeEmployee($name){
    $role = Role::where('name', $name)->first();
    if($role){
        $this->role()->attach($role->id);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please write your answer in English, as [Stack Overflow is an English site.](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/13676)